# Express Custom Validator always returning Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, express-validator

This is part of my login API used to validate the new user details. The function ifIDAlreadyExist checks the DB and returns true/false for exists/not exists respectively.

Even when the result is false, the error message is returned with the below code. What's wrong with this?

```
const RegInputValdiationRules = () => {
  return [
    check("id")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage("Please enter the login id")
      .custom((value) => {
        ifIDAlreadyExist(value).then((exists) => {
          console.log(exists);
          if (exists === true) return Promise.reject("");
          else return true;
        });
      })
      .withMessage("ID already exists"),
    check("password")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .isLength({ min: 6 })
      .withMessage("Password should contain at least six characters"),
  ];
};
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the error screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing `return` within `custom` method:

```
const RegInputValdiationRules = () => {
  return [
    check("id")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage("Please enter the login id")
      .custom((value) => {
        return ifIDAlreadyExist(value).then((exists) => {
          console.log(exists);
          if (exists === true) return Promise.reject("");
          else return true;
        });
      })
      .withMessage("ID already exists"),
    check("password")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .isLength({ min: 6 })
      .withMessage("Password should contain at least six characters"),
  ];
};
```

Comment: This will cause more errors . Just added it to get what it says.
"Error : cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Comment: @Maya that error is probably coming from your code after the validator, you probably have `res.send` somewhere after the validation, which means it's probably working.. if you can't find it, add the code